# Reading signed and unsigned values from a stream in both byte orders

Tags: vb.net

I need to read signed and unsigned 8 bit, 16 bit and 32 bit values from a file stream which may be little-endian or big-endian (it happens to be a tiff file which carries the byte order indicator at the start).

I initially started by writing my own functions to read the values and was able to do so for unsigned values.  e.g.

```
Public Function ReadUInt32() As UInt32
    Dim b(4) As Byte
    input.Read(b, 0, 4)
    Dim out As UInt32 = CUInt(If(IsBigEndian, b(0), b(3))) << 24
    out += CUInt(If(IsBigEndian, b(1), b(2))) << 16
    out += CUInt(If(IsBigEndian, b(2), b(1))) << 8
    out += CUInt(If(IsBigEndian, b(3), b(0)))
    Return out
End Function
```

But then I started looking at signed values and my brain broke.

As an alternative, I found the IO.BinaryReader which will let me read signed values directly but doesn't seem to have any way to indicate that the data is big-endian or little-endian.

Is there a nice way of handling this?  Failing that, can someone tell me how to convert multiple bytes into signed values (in both byte orders)?

Answer (score 0):

It's not ideal, but you can use the various overloads of the HostToNetworkOrder and NetworkToHostOrder methods from the [System.Net.IPAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw3e4a0f.aspx) class to do signed-integer endian conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the BitConverter Class?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.bitconverter_members(v=VS.80).aspx

Some byte shuffling and a call to ToUInt32 should get what you want.